# I'm trying to store the geolocation in some variables outside of the functions scope, js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, w3c-geolocation

I want to store the geolocation but when I go and store the latitude and longitude in variables outside the scope they won't store. Does anybody know why this is the case? I've tried with undefined variables too but that hasn't worked either.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var location = {lat:'', lon:''};

function updateLocation(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            location.lon = position.coords.longitude;
        });
    }
}

updateLocation();

$("#data").html("lat: " + location.lat + " lon: " + location.lon);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 big issues with your code:

1. You try to call `updateLocation`**before** the function is defined. `updateLocation` is defined inside `$(document).ready`, while the calling happens outside. Please execute everything only when the document is ready.
2. `location` is a name preserved for `window.location`. While using that name is ok, it is highly recommended to change that variable name to avoid confusion and wrong behaviors.